# Clean toString from JodaTime Period

Tags: jodatime

I'm calling toString() (or difference.normalizedStandard().toString()) on a Period object, and getting "`PT-10H0.317S`"

Why is the default toString so inconvenient? What does this string even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The period toString is defined in `AbstractPeriod#toString()`, which delegates to `ISOPeriodFormat`. Here's the JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * The standard ISO format - PyYmMwWdDThHmMsS.
 * Milliseconds are not output.
 * Note that the ISO8601 standard actually indicates weeks should not
 * be shown if any other field is present and vice versa.
 *
 * @return the formatter
 */
```

...so apparently it's the ISO 8601 standard format for periods of time. To take manual control of the output, use `org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder`.